# Function not taking position from camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The program doesn't take the position from the screen when you press the mouse unless you're clicking over the player

This program should take the vectors from the position of mousedown and mouseup and apply a constant force to the player, but mousedown is activated only when you're pressing over the player (it works if you release the mouse anywhere else). If it can help, the main camera is parented under the player game object

```
void OnMouseDown()
{

    mouseDown = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
}


void OnMouseUp()
{
    if (!thrown)    //verifica che non sia stato lanciato
    {
        mouseUp = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        var force = fixedLaunch(mouseDown - mouseUp);
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        GetComponent<ConstantForce2D>().force = force * speed;
        thrown = true;
        StartCoroutine(waiter(delay));
    }
}
```

it should take the vector from when you press the mouse button and when you release it from anywhere on the screen to create a vector, instead it works only when you press on the player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem (about a week ago), instead of using OnMouseDown() and OnMouseUp() I've written the code in Update() and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the desired behavior. As per Unity Scripting Documentation:

> OnMouseDown is called when the user has pressed the mouse button while over the GUIElement or Collider.
>
> OnMouseUp is called when the user has released the mouse button.

If you want it to capture mouse clicks anywhere on the screen, you may want to attach your script to a Canvas instead of you player gameobject.

**Edit to answer the comment below:**

Attach it to the canvas, and add:

```
public GameObject playerObject;
```

In the inspector reference it to your player.
Then in your script apply the force to it, or call a function on a script attached to your player if you prefer.

Otherwise, you can use in `Update()`

```
if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){//do your stuff;}
if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {//do your other stuff;}
```

Comment: I can't attach the script to anything else except the Player cause it has to apply the force to it. I've tried putting a trigger on the camera but it still doesn't work if not on the player

Comment: Updated the answer to reply to your comment.